# NFC & Kotlin: How to share a String between 2 devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I was reading [this article](https://expertise.jetruby.com/a-complete-guide-to-implementing-nfc-in-a-kotlin-application-5a94c5baf4dd) about NFC and Kotlin and tried to implement the Code in my App. I want to send a string from one device (from the customer) to the receiving device (supplier) for a faster checking - in (for example if you have booked a table, the device reads the booking-id from the customer-app and displays the regarding information on the supplier-device.
The problem is that:

```
       this.nfcAdapter?.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(outcomingNfcCallback, this)
        this.nfcAdapter?.setNdefPushMessageCallback(outcomingNfcCallback, this)
```

both Callbacks from the NFC Adapter are deprecated since API 29.

So is there any other way left to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessageCallback(android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...)) mentions the following concerning the deprecation:

> File sharing can work using other technology like Bluetooth.

Indicating the feature was originally intended for file sharing,
not the sending of short strings.

Two solutions come to mind:

- On the customer's device you generate a QR code containing the string you want to send over. With the supplier's device you scan the QR code. This way is often used for mobile payment and customer reward/discount apps.
- A web service where the customer sends over their ID and then information is returned from a database.

You can also combine these approaches by for example letting the customer scan a static printed QR code containing the supplier ID. With the supplier ID your app could then submit the customer's booking ID and the supplier ID to your web service after which booking info is returned.